# Using a UISlider to change volume

Tags: cocoa-touch

What's the best way to use a UISlider to change the volume of the iPhone in an app?

---

I've tried using that Bill ([Using a UISlider to change volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463034/iphone-sdk-uislider-to-change-volume#463970))

But nothing appears on the screen using the code:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                CGRectMake(0, 0, 215, 22)] autorelease];
volumeView.center = CGPointMake(150,375);
[volumeView sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using a UISlider to change volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463034/iphone-sdk-uislider-to-change-volume#465649)

^ I tried that lostintransit, however this is not changing the **ringer volume**. It comes up on the iphone screen, but doesn't change anything. Even using the demo project provided.

Comment: Are you trying it on the simulator? It won't work on the sim. Try your code on an actual phone. I am using this in one of my apps and it works pretty good.

Comment: you need to import the mediaplayer framerwork: #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

Answer (score 15):

I've just found a very easy way. Instead of coding, just place it in your XIB.

1. Open the XIB where you want to place to slider into
2. Add a UIView to your view
3. Change the class identity from UIView to MPVolumeView
4. Change backgroundColor to clear

Voila!

PS: Tested it on a device with iPhone OS 3.0. As lostInTransit stated before, it won't work on the simulator.

Comment: You've forgotten to mention that MediaPlayer framework must be added to the project to have this working.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this same technique, however I am noticing the following behavior:

On an iPod touch G2:
The MPVolumeView slider works and fully responds to the rocker switch from app startup time.

On an iPhone Gen 1 and 3G:
The MPVolumeView slider doesn't start changing the volume until media playback has occurred via the AudioQueue APIs, and will stop changing the volume when AudioSessionSetActive(false) is called. Even more bizarre: if you hit the rocker switch on the iPhone while using the AudioQueue APIs during playback then the MPVolumeView slider will work for the rest of the lifetime of the app.

[This code](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/09/proper-usage-of-mpvolumeview-class.html) keeps everything in sync, and tends to help with ensuring that the rocker switch and the slider stay in sync, but it doesn't eliminate the issues I am having with MPVolumeView on an iPhone.

All of my experience here is under iPhone OS 3.0 with the iPhone 3.0 SDK.

I hope this helps narrow down your problem somewhat.

My next tactic was to start doing things with kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute and try alternate values for kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory to see what happens.

Side note:
Thanks to everyone on the IB techniques for creation and managing the MPVolumeView. I was using code to create and place it, and I keep forgetting about the technique where you can set the type of the UIView in IB.

Side note 2:
In working with the MPVolumeView I discovered that if you set the audio category to anything other than kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback that the MPVolumeView will display the text "iPhone..." when the iPhone is set to silent mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use an MPVolumeView to display a slider that allows the user to modify the system volume.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change the iPhone volume, MPVolumeView is the only option. Try the example on this link.

http://www.stormyprods.com/blogger/2008/09/proper-usage-of-mpvolumeview-class.html