# For the iPad or iPhone, how do you control the system Volume? For example, have a button that mutes all audio

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, ipad, mute

I would like to make a button in my iPad app (probably will be similar to iPhone apps) that when I push this button, all audio is muted, even when you exit the app.

I don't see anyway that you can control the volume, although I'm sure other apps have that I have seen in the app store for the iPhone. I also read some places that doing this would reject you from the app store.

How could I go about lowering, or highering the volume of the iPad from an app that works even when the app closes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't, at least not programmatically.   But you can integrate an MPVolumeView.

[Using a UISlider to change volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463034/using-a-uislider-to-change-volume)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Apple does not let you make system-wide changes that affect other apps like this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's a private API. Using private APIs gets you rejected from the App Store.

Comment: If you get rejected, is it permanent? Like could I use it and give it a shot and if they accept it I'm lucky?

Comment: They have automated systems for detecting private APIs. Don't waste your time.