# iPhone: Implement Volume control using buttons

Tags: iphone, volume, mpvolumeview

Could anyone please tell me how could I implement the functionality of adjusting the volume on button click? Basically I am trying to put two buttons Volume Up and Volume Down but I couldn't find anyway to adjust the volume of button click. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463034/using-a-uislider-to-change-volume) link mentions about the MPVolumeView but I can't find it in my XCode 4.0 objects list and also I am not sure if I can use that for button click volume adjust. Could someone please point me in correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your looking to have buttons to tell the iPhone to adjust the volume up or down. Although you may have better luck achieving this with a UIProgressView 
I would try playing around with something like this, either with multiple intended volumes each defined by the selected button, or create a variable and add or subtract from it in the ibaction ex myAudio.volume = x+.5;

...

- (IBAction) VolumeOne {
  myAudio.volume = 1.0;
  }