# can i control over all volume of iphone using iphone app

Tags: iphone, volume

Can I control over all volume of iPhone using my app ?
Because I want to control the volume of all play back apps

Comment: Hope not http://usgovinfo.about.com/b/2008/06/20/bill-would-lower-tv-commercial-volume.htm

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

It appears possible at least on some versions: see [Using a UISlider to change volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463034/using-a-uislider-to-change-volume#465649)

Comment: My requirement is not to use slider but mute the playback audio just after 1 minute of starting

Answer (score 0):

[MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) gives you an on screen control to display and control the system volume. This has the advantage of other approaches that it will also allow you to control which airplay device to stream the audio too. Here is an example of how to add it to your view hierarchy.

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: volumeViewRect] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview: myVolumeView];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AVAudioPlayer to play this, then just use the

```
[audio stop];
```

Method in order to pause after one minute (maybe hook it up to a NSTimer).